# WHy is chrome is redirecting some support sites to https://doublestat.info/c

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Forgive me if this is the wrong forum for this.
I have a Chrome installation that is redirecting some other websites "support" pages to this url https://doublestat.info/c

It doesn't appear to be anything.
I have done a check in chrome for malware/ phishing software etc.
I have tried the site in question in Firefox and IE - no issue there.

Extension installed:

- Web Store : version 0_2
- Library Extension : version 2023_1127_1
- OneTab : version 1_84
- Textarea Cache : version 4_5_0
- Mailto: for Gmail™ : version 2_6
- Empty New Tab Page : version 1_2_0
- Adobe Acrobat: PDF edit, convert, sign tools : version 23_12_1_0
- Video Downloader - click&save : version 0_1_2
- Markdown Here : version 2_12_0
- Notepad : version 6_1_1
- Google Docs Offline : version 1_73_0
- LastPass: Free Password Manager : version 4_125_0_4
- Evercontact : version 2_5
- Todoist for Chrome : version 11_1
- Gmail Inline Image Fit : version 1_0_2
- Application Launcher For Drive (by Google) : version 3_10
- Open in Brave Browser : version 0_1_3
- Chrome PDF Viewer : version 1
- User JavaScript and CSS : version 1_2_8
- Google Network Speech : version 1_0
- Save to Pocket : version 4_0_6
- Google Hangouts : version 1_3_21
- Chrome Web Store Payments : version 1_0_0_6

Comment: Appears to only be zendesk that it is redirecting

Comment: How is your question related to a programming-specific issue?

Comment: Have you tried to disable all these extensions ?

Comment: Please try disabling the extensions thereafter enable gradually to find the culprit

Comment: @DarkBee I am not sure which forum is best for this, as I said in the question.

Comment: @Ahmedaminshahin I have, essentially by using Incognito mode... same issue.

I think it is probably malware, I was looking for advice, as the scans are not finding anything.

Comment: @CraigLambie if you have windows, go to system32/drivers/etc and locate host, find any website relative to what popup for you, usually this file is the root of all DNS corruptions. you can edit this file using notepad.

Comment: @Ahmedaminshahin thanks for the tip. I had a look, nothing unusual in there that I can see....

Answer (score 1):

when you visit a website, there is a redirect setup from their cPanel, and you cannot control that unless you are the host manager.

if you are experiencing redirect to other pages when you randomly visit websites from your chrome browser, it is most probably a malware infection on your browser/system.

My advice is to reset your chrome browser or uninstall it and reinstall it again, download a good anti-virus such as bit defender, Norton, viper or any other good antivirus and make a full scan.

Also, you can run.
sfc /scan
by going to your command prompt to check any corruption on your OS.

hope this helps.